# How create distinct automapping?

Tags: c#, automapper

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Product, SelectListOptionItem>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

I need use distinct for Product.TypeId

Comment: What do you mean with "distinct for Product.TypeId"? Distinct in what aspect?

Comment: I mean unique product by TypeId

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. AutoMapper maps one instance of type `TFrom` to one instance of type `TTo`. Distinct is simply not applicable here.

Comment: Thanks. I will create view in database. p.s What to do for this post? close or delete?

Comment: I would delete it if I were you.